# Computer not reading last number from a text file

Tags: java

For my  assignment I was to make a program that would read and print the numbers from a text file, then calculate the sum and the average of those numbers. My program does that just fine. The only problem I have is that the program will not read the last number from my text file. The numbers on the file read:

```
3
8
1
13
18
15
7
17
1
14
0
12
3
2
5 
4
```

For some reason the computer will not read the number 4.

Here is my program:

```
{ //begin testshell 
public static void main (String[] args)
{ //begin main
    System.out.println("Scores");
    Scanner inFile=null;
    try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("ints.dat"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        System.out.println ("File not found!");
        // Stop program if no file found
        System.exit (0);
        }

   // sets sum at 0 so numbers will be added
   int sum=0;

   int num= inFile.nextInt();

   // starts counting the amount of numbers so average can be calculated
   int numberAmount=0;

    while(inFile.hasNext()) 
    {       
        // print the integer
        System.out.println(num);

        // adds the number to 0 and stores the new number into the variable sum
        sum = num+sum;

        // increases the number of numbers 
        numberAmount++;
        // reads the next integer
        num = inFile.nextInt();
    }
    inFile.close();
    // calculates average
    double average = (double)sum/(double)numberAmount;
    average = Math.round (average * 100.0) / 100.0;  

    //output
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers = "+sum);
    System.out.println("The number of scores = "+numberAmount);
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers = "+average);

    }//end main
}//end testshell
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program reads the last number, but it doesn't use it,
look at this part:

> ```
> while(inFile.hasNext()) 
> {       
>     // ...
>     sum = num+sum;
>
>     // reads the next integer
>     num = inFile.nextInt();
> }
> ```

The last number is read, but never added to `sum`.

You need to reorder the statements:

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {       
    int num = inFile.nextInt();

    System.out.println(num);

    sum += num;

    numberAmount++;
}
```

Comment: THIS WORKS! Thank you so much